# Numerical solution of two coupled second order differential equations of motion

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, projectile, computational-physics

Is there a numerical algorithm for solving a pair of coupled second order differential equations?

This question arises from a homework problem that I have that involves two dimensional projectile motion. The problem is as follows:

> *An object is fired through a viscous fluid that has a dampening force proportional to the velocity raised to the $n$'th power. For what values of $n$ and magnitude of the force is the maximum range achieved for an launch angle greater than $\pi$/4?*

The equations of motion I worked out are below.

$ m \ddot{x}=-km\dot x(\dot x^2+\dot y^2)^{\frac{n-1}2}$

$  \ddot{x}=-k\dot x(\dot x^2+\dot y^2)^{\frac{n-1}2}$

$ m \ddot{y}=-km\dot y(\dot x^2+\dot y^2)^{\frac{n-1}2}-mg$

$ \ddot{y}=-k\dot y(\dot x^2+\dot y^2)^{\frac{n-1}2}-g$

If you make the substitutions $\tilde x=\frac{x}{k^{n-1}}$, $\tilde y=\frac{y}{k^{n-1}}$, and $\tilde g={g}{k^{n-1}}$ you then eliminate one degree of freedom *k* and the equations become:

$  \ddot{\tilde{x}}=-\dot{\tilde{x}}(\dot{\tilde{x}}^2+\dot{\tilde{y}}^2)^{\frac{n-1}2}$

$ \ddot{\tilde{y}}=-\dot{\tilde{y}}(\dot{\tilde{x}}^2+\dot{\tilde{y}}^2)^{\frac{n-1}2}-\tilde g$

There should be a numerical algorithm for solving a pair of coupled second order differential equations with the following starting conditions with the answer ending at some time $\ t$

$\tilde{x}_0=0, \tilde{y}_0=0, v_0=1, \dot{\tilde{x}}_0=\cos(\theta _0), \dot{\tilde{y}}_0=\sin(\theta _0)$

Then use a root finding algorithm, I planned on bisection, to find the $ t_f$ for which $y=0$ and the $x(t_f)=Range$ I would then cycle through different values $\theta_0$ and compare the value of the range to the range for  $\theta _0=\pi /4$ and note if any of the values are larger. Then this process could be repeated for varying $n$.

Does this sound solid? And if so is there a numerical recipe for coupled second order differential equations?

Comment: There are countless numerical approaches to solve coupled second order ODE's... but all of them are off-topic here. SciComp.SE would be better.

Comment: Why would you need a root finding algorithm? are you trying to use some kind of implicit integrator for your equation?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about numerical methods

Comment: This is more like a first order equation - treat your variables as $\dot{x}$ and $\dot{y}$. (it IS a first order equation in $\dot{x}$ and $\dot{y}$.)

Comment: First I wanted to make sure that this method is sound before wasting time coding this up. Then I wanted to find an algorithm, something like a Runge-Kutta.

Comment: If I treat this as coupled first order differential equations, Which I already have, it would only give me velocity information not range information.

Comment: Why don't you simply use Runge-Kutta directly?

Comment: I just did the Runge-Kutta. I did not know how to apply the Runge-Kutta to this problem when I first posed it, but now I  have solved the problem directly in that way.